# Why is charCodeAt() influenced by a ">" character in a comment line in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

The following script shows the code of the character "¶".
When executed in Firefox, the result is the correct value 182 (0xB6).
When executed in Google Chrome, the result is 35386.
However, the result is also 182 if you remove the ">" character from the comment line.
Is this a bug or is there a logical explanation?
Note: The codePointAt() operation behaves the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
<script>
// a>b
a = "¶ELLO";
b = a.charCodeAt(0);
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = b;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> When executed in Google Chrome, the result is 35386.

I've been able to replicate that locally. It is, as I suspected, down to text encoding.

You have the file stored in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (or possibly [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) text encoding, but the file doesn't say what encoding it uses and apparently your server (if any) isn't specifying the correct encoding. So the browser has to "guess" at the text encoding and apparently is getting it wrong.

If you store the file in UTF-8, or identify the correct encoding (Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1) when you serve it, you'll get consistent results across browsers. I'd suggest *both* storing it in UTF-8 and identifying that in the `head` of the file (via [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset)):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<body>
```

...but you can keep using your current encoding if you want, just update the file and/or server configuration to correctly identify it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="Windows-1252">
    </head>
<body>
<p id="p" />
<script>
// a>b
a = "¶ELLO";
b = a.charCodeAt(0);
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = b;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Side note: [`p`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) is not a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements). `<p .../>` and `<p ...>` do exactly the same thing in HTML: It's a *start tag* for a paragraph. I'd suggest not using the `/` at the end in the normal case in HTML, since it's misleading to the next person working on the file. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you did not specify a charset for your file and the browsers you've mentioned do have different default charsets. When I save the file to my disk as UTF-8, specifying UTF-8 as charset in the file, the result is 182 in chrome, firefox and edge!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p id="p" />
<script>
// a>b
a = "¶ELLO";
b = a.charCodeAt(0);
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = b;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```